# Excel VBA: Fill stacked diagram (and treemap-diagram) with images based on cell value

Tags: vba, excel, diagram

I'm trying to fill a stacked excel-diagram with images based on a cell value. I can do it for the first column, but not for the second.

Here's an example. I want to fill the orange area with an images based on the values in column B

[image: Image: stacked diagram]

And here's the VBA-code how i fill the first column with an image:

```
Sub fill_with_image()
    With Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection(1)
        Set vAddress = ActiveSheet.Range(Split(Split(.Formula, ",")(1), "!")(1))
        For i = 1 To vAddress.Cells.Count
            imagefile = Cells(i + 1, 1).Value
            .Points(i).Format.Fill.UserPicture (imagefile & ".png")
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

The second part of my question: I can't find any documentation how to fill treemap-diagrams with images. Any idea if its possible?

[image: Image Treemap-Diagram]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just loop to select `SeriesCollection(2)`

```
Sub fill_with_image()
Dim j as integer    
For j = 1 to 2
    With Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection(j)
    Set vAddress = ActiveSheet.Range(Split(Split(.Formula, ",")(1), "!")(1))
    For i = 1 To vAddress.Cells.Count
        imagefile = Cells(i + 1, 1).Value
        .Points(i).Format.Fill.UserPicture (imagefile & ".png")
    Next i
    End With
Next j
End Sub
```

Comment: I just read that "all of the new charts in 2016 do not include VBA support", so i guess that answers my second part of the question!